# Markov's Inequality Summation Bound

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_{20}$ be independent Poisson random variables with mean 1. Use central limit theorem to approximate the following equation. Use Markov's Inequality to obtain a bound:

$$\Pr\left[\sum_1^{20}X_i>15\right]$$

Since the mean is $1$, the distribution would be $\dfrac{1}{k!e}$. Markov's Inequality states that $\Pr\left[\sum_1^{20}X_i>15\right]\le 1/15$. I don't know how to apply the central limit theorem in this situation, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of the $20$ random variables has expected value $20$ since the expected value of each is $1$.

Have you heard that the sum of independent Poisson-distributed random variables also has a Poisson distribution?  Or that for the Poisson distribution, the expected value is the same as the variance?  So
$$
Z = \frac{\text{sum} - 20}{\sqrt{20}}
$$
has expected value $0$ and standard deviation $1$.

Notice that $\text{sum}>15$ if and only if $\text{sum}\ge 16$.  Should we seek $\Pr\left(Z > \dfrac{15-20}{\sqrt{20}} \right)$ or $\Pr\left(Z \ge \dfrac{16-20}{\sqrt{20}} \right)$?  When approximating this discrete distribution with the $N(0,1)$ distribution, just taking the average, $\dfrac{15+16} 2 = 15.5$, works quite well.

Markov's inequality doesn't say the probability that the sum exceeds $15$ is $\le 1/15$.  It *does* say that the probability that the sum exceeds $15$ times its expected value is $\le1/15$.  But its expected value is $20$, so it tells you the probability that the sum exceeds $15\times20=300$ is $\le 15$.  That's a very weak statement, since that probability is actually microscopic.

You're finding $\Pr(\text{sum}>15)$ and the expected value is $20$, so Markov's inequality just says the probability is $\le \dfrac{20}{16}$, which is more-or-less vacuous, since *all* probabilities of any kind are $\le$ that.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow why I'm suddenly finding Pr(sum >  16) instead of sum > 15? The former omits potential for sum = 16, while the latter does not.

Comment: Typo --- probably came from the earlier mention of $16$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

The "central limit theorem approximation" would replace a sum of $20$ iid Poisson variables with mean $1$ with a normal variable which have the appropriate mean and variance. Since the variance of a Poisson variable with mean $\lambda$ is also $\lambda$ and variances add for independent variables, the mean should be $20$ and the variance should be $20$.

So this gives you a way to make an estimate. An interesting question is: is the estimate any good? A crude way to check is to use Markov's inequality or Chebyshev's inequality.

Comment: Markov's inequality says that if $\Pr(Y\ge0)=1$ then $\Pr(Y>y)\le\dfrac{\operatorname{E}(Y)}{y}$.  It doesn't mention standard deviations. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Honestly I can never keep Markov's and Chebyshev's inequalities straight in the probabilistic context. People seem to constantly switch them back and forth. (I think part of the problem is that, in the most common usage (i.e. the one you've written in that comment), what probabilists call "Markov's inequality" is what analysts call "Chebyshev's inequality".) But I'll remove that, since you seem to be right in this context.